# How to move *ngIf conditions from template to typescript file in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 2.I have to display Yes and No label based on certain conditions.The same label should get replaced.For that,I am writing *ngIf condition in my template file with OR operators.It makes my template look clumsy so I want to declare those *ngIf condition in my typescript file and use the variable instead in my template with *ngIf.

Also, is there any way to achieve 'Yes' and 'No' placeholders with one md-input?If yes, then how to do that?

My template-

```
<md-input *ngIf="cond1 || cond2" placeholder="Yes"></md-input>
<md-input *ngIf="cond3||cond4||cond5" placeholder="No"></md-input>

<input type="button" [disabled]="placeholder==='YES'" value="Save">
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<md-input [placeholder]="placeholder"></md-input>
```

```
class MyComponent {

  get placeholder() {
    if (cond1 || cond2) {
      return 'YES';
    } else if (cond3 || cond4 || cond5) {
      return 'NO';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we use get like that or it should be a function?

Comment: You can remove `get` and then use it like `[placeholder]="placeholder()"`. This way you also can pass parameters.

Comment: cool! but the value is not changing now.Its always showing Yes.

Comment: Seems to indicate that `cond1 || cond2` is always `true`

Comment: cond 1 to cond 5 are select dropdown values.The placeholder value should get updated based on the value selected from the dropdown.

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker? I don't have enough information to make conclusions.

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: In addition to the above, How can I enable/disable a button that I have based on the 'YES' or 'NO' text. Help much appreciated.

Comment: `<button [disabled]="placeholder==="YES">` but I'd find it better to return `true` and `false` (as value, not as string) from `placeholder()` and then use it like `<button [disabled]="!placeholder>` and `<md-input [placeholder]="placeholder ? 'YES' : 'NO'"></md-input>`

Comment: 'YES' and 'NO' are the labels here so I am supposed to use as a string.I am trying to use like above but that's not enabling the button when its 'NO'.

Comment: It might need `[disabled]="placeholder==="YES ? true : null"` or `[attr.disabled]="placeholder==="YES ? true : null"`. I haven't used md2 components myself yet.